# Passing an object from Javascript to C++

Tags: javascript, c++, iwebbrowser2

I have found [Passing an array from Javascript to C++](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Web_Development/Web_Languages-Standards/ASP/Q_11577838.html) solution, but I have another task: Passing **an object** from Javascript to C++ (if I use IWebBrowser2 with IDispatch)

I mean that I need call C++ method via window.external.method with JavaScript object argument

```
var obj = {name: "Petr", group: "Friend"};
window.external.myMethod(obj);
```

How to get access to object member "name", "group", etc. ?

Comment: ok, so, what about given question?

Comment: What about reviewing your questions now that someone helped you? ;D

Comment: I already do it :) At once after your note

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the object's properties via the [`IDispatch`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms221608.aspx) interface and its methods [`GetIDsOfNames`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms221306.aspx) and [`Invoke`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms221479.aspx).

Depending on your definition of `myMethod`, you should be receiving `obj` as either a [`VARIANT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms221627.aspx) or an `IDispatch *` in your C++ code. If a `VARIANT`, `vt` should be `VT_DISPACTH`, in which case you can safely dereference `pdispval`.

Once you have an `IDispatch` pointer, you can use `GetIDsOfNames` to get the [`DISPID`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms221242.aspx) for a property that you're interested in like so:

```
_bstr_t sPropertyName = L"myProperty";
DISPID dispid = 0;
HRESULT hr = pDispatch->GetIDsOfNames(IID_NULL, &sPropertyName, 1, LOCALE_SYSTEM_DEFAULT, &dispid);
if(SUCCEEDED(hr))
{
    ...
```

Once you have successfully received your `DISPID`, you must call `Invoke` differently according to whether you would like to get a value, set a value or call a method.

For instance, to get a value:

```
    VARIANT vValue;
    hr = pDispatch->Invoke(dispid, IID_NULL, LOCALE_SYSTEM_DEFAULT, DISPATCH_PROPERTYGET, 0, &vValue, 0, 0);
    if(SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        ...
```

See the documentation for `Invoke` for more information about the different permutations when calling it.

Comment: very nice, only one question - how can we enumerate all members of object?

Comment: I try use pDispatch->GetTypeInfo => ITypeInfo::GetNames - but something wrong :(

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to be able to read the object fields, the most flexible way is to use JSON.

On your web page side use:

var obj = {name: "Petr", group: "Friend"};
window.external.myMethod(JSON.stringify(obj));

On your C++ side define myMethod() to accept a single string argument. Then use a [C++ JSON parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/245973/whats-the-best-c-json-parser) to parse this argument into a readable object.

Comment: I known and doing it now but I think it possible in the same way link in article above, but I am not such advanced user in COM :((

Comment: The article above is in ExpertsExchange. I do not think it's a good idea to link them on SO...

Comment: I am not registered at ExpertsExchange.

Answer (score 0):

```
static HRESULT \
IDispatch_VarGet (IDispatch *pRDisp, LPOLESTR Name, VARIANT *pVarRes)
{
    DISPPARAMS DispParams;
    DISPID dispid;
    HRESULT hr;

    if ((hr = IDispatch_GetIDsOfNames (pRDisp, &IID_NULL,
                &Name, 1, LOCALE_SYSTEM_DEFAULT, &dispid)))
        return hr;

    ZeroMemory (&DispParams, sizeof (DispParams));

    hr = IDispatch_Invoke (pRDisp, dispid, &IID_NULL,
            LOCALE_SYSTEM_DEFAULT, DISPATCH_PROPERTYGET,
            &DispParams, pVarRes, NULL, NULL);

    return hr;
}


static HRESULT \
IDispatch_VarPut (IDispatch *pRDisp, LPOLESTR Name, VARIANT *pVarArg)
{
    DISPPARAMS DispParams;
    DISPID dispid, ndispid;
    HRESULT hr;

    if ((hr = IDispatch_GetIDsOfNames (pRDisp, &IID_NULL,
                &Name, 1, LOCALE_SYSTEM_DEFAULT, &dispid)))
        return hr;

    ndispid = DISPID_PROPERTYPUT;

    DispParams.rgvarg = pVarArg;
    DispParams.rgdispidNamedArgs = &ndispid;
    DispParams.cArgs  = 1;
    DispParams.cNamedArgs = 1;

    hr = IDispatch_Invoke (pRDisp, dispid, &IID_NULL,
            LOCALE_SYSTEM_DEFAULT, DISPATCH_PROPERTYPUT,
            &DispParams, NULL, NULL, NULL);

    return hr;
}


static HRESULT \
IDispatch_StrPut (IDispatch *pRDisp, LPOLESTR Name, LPOLESTR StrVal)
{
    VARIANT varg;
    HRESULT hr;

    VariantInit (&varg);

    V_VT   (&varg) = VT_BSTR;
    V_BSTR (&varg) = SysAllocString (StrVal);

    hr = IDispatch_VarPut (pRDisp, Name, &varg);

    VariantClear (&varg);

    return hr;
}


static HRESULT \
IDispatch_IntPut (IDispatch *pRDisp, LPOLESTR Name, int IntVal)
{
    VARIANT varg;
    HRESULT hr;

    VariantInit (&varg);

    V_VT (&varg) = VT_I4;
    V_I4 (&varg) = IntVal;

    hr = IDispatch_VarPut (pRDisp, Name, &varg);

    VariantClear (&varg);

    return hr;
}
```

...

```
if ((hr = IDispatch_StrPut (pRDisp, L"code", buff)))
    return hr;

if ((hr = IDispatch_IntPut (pRDisp, L"state", state)))
    return hr;
```

...

```
{
    // ...
    VariantInit (&varg);

    if ((hr = IDispatch_VarGet (pRDisp, L"code", &varg)))
    {
        VariantClear (&varg);
        return hr;
    }

    if (V_VT (&varg) == VT_BSTR)

    // ...

    VariantClear (&varg);
    return hr;
}
```

and jave code sample...

```
var frec = {code:'', state:0};

frec.code = row.cells[0].innerHTML;
external.FeatureStateChg (frec);
_featState (row.cells[2], frec.state);
```

...

```
var frec = {code:'', name:'', state:0};

if (!external.FeaturesEnum (frec, i))
    break;
```

Comment: Some explanation is also appreciated